# What is Maximum Decimal Value using RS Logix 500 for a Long Integer Data File?

Tags: long-integer

Using RS Logix 500, what is the maximum decimal value for a Long Integer Data File?
I know the 32nd bit determines a negative or positive value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did the math myself, I should quit being so lazy.
2,147,483,647